# Tinymce removing noshade from hr

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

My tinymce is working wonderfully, all except for when you paste an hr tag. The styles seem to paste with it. I am removing styles on paste and have considered removing the hr altogether, but that just isn't an option.

This is what I'm working on

```
tinyMCE.init({
  script_url : '../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
  mode : "exact",
  elements : "wStory",
  theme : "advanced",
  plugins : "paste",
  invalid_elements: "noshade, size",
  theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,hr,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent, indent,|,cleanup,|,forecolor, |,undo,redo,|,link, unlink,|,code,|, help",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
  theme_advanced_path : false,
  theme_advanced_resizing : false,
  cleanup_on_startup : true,
  fix_list_elements : false,
  fix_nesting : false,
  fix_table_elements : false,
  paste_use_dialog : true,
  paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
  height: "700px",
  width: "100%",  
});
```

Just to be clear, I would like this

```
<hr noshade="noshade">
```

to become this

```
<hr>
```

I have tried declaring valid elements and just removing the noshade tag, but it seems in the latest version of tinymce that is not valid. Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: ok, tinymce4 is still beta. Why don't you save yourself the trouble and use the stable 3.5.8?

Comment: because I already have everything already programmed out except for this tiny issue and I don't have time to strip everything and redo it completely.